# Cannot route traffic to AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment using Route 53 and custom domain under the same account of AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have been trying to host our php website using Elastic Beanstalk however I had no luck under Hosted Zones. Domain is registered with the same AWS account.

Things I did:

- Created a hosted zone named mycustomdomain.com
- Created a A type record set with ALIAS to my environment. (Selected through drop down of AWS itself.)

The domain name of EB Environment

`environmentname.randomclashofcharacters.region.elasticbeanstalk.com`

assigned by AWS works flawlessly so I can say that there is nothing wrong with the config at Elastic Beanstalk side of things.

[I followed through the guide uploaded by AWS themselves](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html#routing-to-beanstalk-environment-create-alias-procedure)

I see one weird thing that might be causing that. The name servers listed under domain name is different from ones listed in Hosted Zone. Should I change them. AWS guide doesn't says to do so, so I didn't do it.

Thanks for your help beforehand.

Cheers,

~bio

Comment: Yes... You need to change the name servers of the domain to the ones in the NS record of the hosted zone.

Comment: @hephalump Should I request the change of DNS from registered domains selection or should I change the NS record under the hosted zone.

Comment: Go to the registered domain settings and update them there.

Comment: @hephalump Thanks for the answer, I just updated them and they are identical now. But cannot still access the Elastic Beanstalk with custom domain. Should I wait for a while for  name servers?

Comment: Yes. Propagation can take up to 48 house, but usually is live within ~15 mins.

Comment: I have 4 record sets right now. One A aliased to EB Environment. One MX. NS and SOA from at their default state. Should I add anything else?

Comment: Negative; should be good.

Comment: Thanks mate, I will wait for a while, if it is solved going to answer my question mentioning you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to corrective help from @heplalump the problem is resolved. I actually needed to make domain's name-servers same with the hosted zones. Still cannot reach from desktop Safari but reachable via chrome and iPhone safari. If you want to do this procedure for yourself just follow the guide amazon provided.